# Insert list of objects with MyBatis annotation

Tags: java, mybatis

I know how to insert list of values with xml config mapper, but I want to do it with annotation.

Something like this, but working

```
@Insert("insert into  tableName (param1, param2) values (#{obj1.param1}, #{obj1.param2})")
void insert(@Param("obj1") List<MyObject> obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in XML you do it with `foreach`, then it is the same in annotation, just surround with `<script>` tags.

```
@Insert({"<script>", 
         "insert into  tableName (param1, param2) values ", 
         "<foreach collection='obj1' item='o' separator = ', ' open ="(" close=")" >#{o}</foreach>",
         "</script>"})
void insert(@Param("obj1") List<MyObject> obj1);
```

Comment: blackwizard, thank you for answer.
Of course it's solution, but not graceful. I didn't find any way to do it with standard way(without script). So finally I do it with xml, because it's more readable